# How to make these graphs?

Tags: statistics, graphing-functions

I want to plot four variables in the same graph [like these here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPAkf.png)

Can someone please help me with these. I don't understand how to have those two perspective grid in the graph.

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to plot four variables in the same graph like in the top of the linked image.